# Are there any limits on the number of Azure Storage Tables allowed in one account?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm currently trying to store a fairly large and dynamic data set.

My current design is tending towards a solution where I will create a new table every few minutes - this means every table will be quite compact, it will be easy for me to search my data (I don't need everything in one table) and it should make it easy for me to delete stale data.

I've looked and I can't see any documented limits - but I wanted to check:

- Is there any limit on the number of tables allowed within one Azure storage account?
- Or can I keep adding potentially thousands of tables without any concern?

Comment: However there is a limit on operations/second on one account, I think it is Up to 5,000 entities/messages/blobs per second per account.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/05/10/windows-azure-storage-abstractions-and-their-scalability-targets.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are no published limits to the number of tables, only the <strike>100TB</strike> 500TB limit on a given storage account. Combined with partition+row, it sounds like you'll have a direct link to your data without running into any table-scan issues.

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179338.aspx) explicitly calls out: "You can create any number of tables within a given storage account, as long as each table is uniquely named." Have fun!